# 100th derivative of $(1-2x)^{2/3}$ at point $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$$\frac{\mathrm d^{100}}{\mathrm dx^{100}} (1-2x)^{2/3}$$
Without Taylor.

I relay don't have any idea how to use General Leibniz rule in this case.

Comment: What's the first derivative?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it helps or makes it messier but $y=(1-2x)^{2/3}$ satisfies $3 y^2 y'''+6 (y')^3+18 y y' y'' = 0$.

Comment: The very first thing that came to my mind is to use **the binomial series**. :) But you prevented using such things!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac d{dx} f(x)^n=nf(x)^{n-1}f'(x)$$

If $f'(x)=k$ for some constant $k$

$$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}f(x)^n=n(n-1)...(n-m+1)f(x)^{n-m} k^m$$

Comment: $f'(x)$ is not constant. This is not true. :)

Comment: @H.R. it works if we let $f(x)=1-2x$

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- $$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left[\left(1-2x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right]=(-2)^n\cdot(1-2x)^{\frac{2}{3}-n}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}-n\right)}$$

---

So:
$$\frac{\text{d}^{100}}{\text{d}x^{100}}\left[\left(1-2x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right]=(-2)^{100}\cdot(1-2x)^{\frac{2}{3}-100}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}-100\right)}=$$
$$2^{100}\cdot(1-2x)^{-\frac{298}{3}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{295}{3}\right)}$$

And in the point $x=0$:

$$2^{100}\cdot(1-2\cdot0)^{-\frac{298}{3}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{295}{3}\right)}=2^{100}\cdot(1-0)^{-\frac{298}{3}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{295}{3}\right)}=$$
$$2^{100}\cdot(1)^{-\frac{298}{3}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{295}{3}\right)}=2^{100}\cdot1\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{295}{3}\right)}=\frac{2^{100}\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{295}{3}\right)}\approx-1.37416\times10^{184}$$